# Both rasterio open and skimage.io.read return a NaN array for the TIFF I am trying to open

Tags: python-3.x, tiff, scikit-image, rasterio

I'm trying to open a SAR image from sentinel-1. I can view the tiff file in QGIS, so I know the data is there, but when I go to open and view/show it in python, all of the modules I could use to open the data produce a NaN area, basically insinuating that there is no data in the image. Visualizing the image produces a completely black image, however the shape is correct.

Here is the code where I read in the image:

```
img = skimage.io.imread('NewData.tif', as_gray = True, plugin = 'tifffile')
with rio.open(r'NewData.tif') as src:
    img2 = src.read()
    imgMeta = src.profile

print(img)

skimage.io.imshow(img)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Why are you opening your raster with both scikit-image and rasterio? What happens when you plot the img2 (the array read from the .tif file using rasterio)? A good way to start troubleshooting NaN issues is to look at the min. and max. values of the array you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not on the way `rasterio` or `skimage` is importing the image, but on the way it is displayed. I am assumign you are working with Calibrated SAR images that ARE NOT converted to the decibel `dB` scale. Here is the problem, the dynamic range of your data.

The issue here is that by default, the color ramp is not being strech according to the distribution of values in the raster histogram. In `QGIS`, `SNAP` or many other EO-related softwares, the color distribution matches the histogram to produce proper visualizations.

**Solution**: either you make that happen in your code or simply convert your backscatter values to decibel (which is a very common procedure when working with SAR data and produces an almost normal distrubution of the data). The conversion can be done in a EO software or more directly in your imported image with:

```
srcdB = 10*np.log10(src)
```

Once done, you can properly display your image:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
import numpy as np

with rio.open(r'/.../S1B_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20190319T161451_20190319T161520_015425_01CE3C_A401_Cal.tif') as src:
    img2 = src.read()
    imgMeta = src.profile
    srcdB = 10*np.log10(src) # to decibel
    show(srcdB, cmap='gray') # show using rasterio
```

[image]